# Display records associated with an ID in a table neatly

Tags: php, html, sql

The code and query work, it displays all the records correctly however everything shows up in a line rather than appearing neatly below. I've tried putting them in a list but it kinda achieves the opposite; it all displays in a list with no real structure.

```
<?php       
    if($state == "Grass")
    { 
        $sql="SELECT t_grassland.landid, t_land.landLocation, t_grassland.grasslandAmount, t_livestock.livestockAnimal, t_livestock.livestockBreed 
            FROM(( t_grassland 
            INNER JOIN t_livestock ON t_grassland.livestockid = t_livestock.livestockid) 
            INNER JOIN t_land ON t_grassland.landID = t_land.landID)
            WHERE t_land.landid = '".$id."';";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

        ?>     

        <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>ID</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Amount</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Animal</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Breed</strong></th>    
                </tr>
            </thead>          

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    { ?>
                        <td><?php echo $row["landid"]; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["landLocation"]; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["grasslandAmount"]; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["livestockAnimal"]; ?> </td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["livestockBreed"]; ?> </td>
                    <?php 
                    } ?>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php       
    } 
        else if ($state == "Growing")
    {
        growingDetails();
    }
    else
    {
        elseDetails();
    } 
?>
```

[image]

Comment: The `<tr>` needs to be _inside_ the while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kindly pointed out by @DinoCoderSaurus, move the `tr` tags to within the loop so that each record in the db will generate a new table row and thus the results will be vertical rather than all in one row

```
   <?php 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["landid"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["landLocation"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["grasslandAmount"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["livestockAnimal"]; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["livestockBreed"]; ?> </td>
    </tr>

    <?php 
        } //end loop
    ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I love missing stuff like this. :D Thank you.